# How to test whether pixel is white in byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, graphics, bitmap, drawing

I'm trying to trim a `Bitmap` based on white pixels. I'd like to do it efficiently, so I'm avoiding using `.GetPixel`

I'm implementing the marked-correct answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820212/automatically-trim-a-bitmap-to-minimum-size). In the answer, they detect whether pixels in a byte array are transparent. I would like to detect whether the pixels are white instead, with a threshold (so if it is less white than a threshold then `foundPixel=true;`.

I've extracted the relevant code here:

```
static Bitmap TrimBitmap(Bitmap source)
{
BitmapData data = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
...
}
```

Detecting the alpha pixel code (**this is what I need help with**):

```
byte alpha = buffer[y * data.Stride + 4 * x + 3];

if (alpha != 0)
{
    foundPixel = true;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Well, you would need to consider the actual pixel format your bitmap (and thus the byte array derived from that bitmap) is using, which will tell you how you should interpret the bytes in the byte array.

Comment: Also, how would you define that threshold exactly? What are  your **exact decision process/rules** to determine whether a particular color is close enough to white or not? This question of mine here is NOT about coding/programming. This is a question about the requirements your program (eventually) has to fullfil.

Comment: @elgonzo the bitmap is loaded from a jpg file

Comment: @elgonzo The threshold is an integer between 1 and 255, which is analogous to the value/lightness of a pixel, like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV . A pixel would be considered white if its lightness value is high enough essentially. You could also think about it so that if any of the red/green/blue colour values fall below the threshold, the pixel is considered non-white

Comment: Whether you got the data from jpg or some other file/source is irrelevant with regard to my comments. Query the bitmap object for the pixel format used (check the documentation for the Bitmap class of how to obtain this information). With regard to threshold, assuming a pixel is a full RGB or RGBA (or variants of them), you will need to convert the RGB pixel values to either HSL or HSV to determine whether its lightness/value falls within the white threshold. (There should be plenty of questions/answers here on SO covering RGB to HSL/HSV conversion...)

Comment: How would I query the bitmap object?

Comment: That's were i said "_check the documentation for the Bitmap class of how to obtain this information_" ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo I've looked into `PixelFormat`; I think I will use `SetPixel`/`GetPixel` because the input images might be of many different formats so I would have to cater for many cases.

Comment: The pixel format is irrelevant since you're requesting the bitmap data as Format32bppArgb with your code. So you will always get it in that format, no matter what format the original image had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're requesting the bitmap data *as* `Format32bppArgb` with your code, the resulting bytes will always be in 4-byte ARGB format. Since this refers to a little-endian `Uint32`, the actual colour components in the bytes are in order B, G, R, A.

To check for white, you just need to check the B, G, R bytes rather than the A one:

```
BitmapData data = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Int32 stride = data.Stride;
source.UnlockBits(data);
Int32 height = source.Height;
Int32 width = source.Width;

Int32 lineStart = 0;
for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    Int32 offset = lineStart;
    for (Int32 x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        byte blue  = buffer[offset + 0];
        byte green = buffer[offset + 1];
        byte red   = buffer[offset + 2];
        //byte alpha = buffer[offset + 3];
        if (blue > threshold && green > threshold && red > threshold)
        {
            // is white pixel.
        }
        offset += 4;
    }
    lineStart += stride;
}
```

`threshold` here is a value close to 255 that determines what value on all three colour components is needed for the pixel to be seen as close enough to white.

Of course, that's not actual cropping code yet, but you should be able to figure it out from there. If you're interested, I posted a crop algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198800/395685), but that one works on one specific value, not on a threshold. Using the above code you could adapt it to your needs.