# How to get the bitmap of the application instead of the screen?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm creating a bitmap of an entire screen, using:

```
 Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm as Image);

            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
```

And then I'm looking for a pixel like so:

```
   for (int x = 0; x < Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color currentPixelColor = bm.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (desiredPixelColor  == currentPixelColor)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Found pixel - - - ");
                        Click(x, y);
                        return true;
                    }
                    
                        
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

For the purpose of searching for a pixel, but this is inefficient because my window size is very small and since the pixel I'm looking for belongs to an object within the application that moves it finds where the object was and not where it is.

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of replacing `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` and the arguments of `CopyFromScreen` with the bounds and location of your window instead of from the whole screen? Or is your issue that the window you're trying to scan is a different application?

Comment: Do note, there are [much, much more efficient methods of iterating over an images to find a colour.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191242/395685)